# SQL query to get custom post type and optional taxonomies

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm using a powerful, low-level plugin ([Exports and Reports](https://wordpress.org/plugins/exports-and-reports/)) to extract content reports from Wordpress. It uses a raw SQL query in order to extract the desired data about my custom post type, in a single table.

Given Wordpress' table structures, especially around taxonomy information, there is a lot of JOINing going on to distill a single table to export.

This is a simplified version (the real one has 3 taxonomies and 3 meta values).

```
SELECT p.post_title,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT type_terms.name) type,
pdf_posts.guid pub_url
FROM
  wp_posts p
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr_type ON p.ID=tr_type.object_id
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tax_type ON tr_type.term_taxonomy_id = tax_type.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN wp_terms type_terms ON tax_type.term_id = type_terms.term_id

  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta_attachment ON meta_attachment.post_id = p.ID
  INNER JOIN wp_posts pdf_posts ON meta_attachment.meta_value = pdf_posts.ID

WHERE 1=1
  AND p.post_type = 'pressmention'
  AND tax_type.taxonomy  = 'pm_type'
  AND meta_attachment.meta_key  = 'pm_pdf_link'
GROUP BY
  p.ID
```

The query works, but only returns a record when all taxonomies and meta values are present in a custom post. I need it to return **all** of the custom posts, whether corresponding taxonomy or meta values exist or not.

So, in the above query, and missing value for the `pm_type` taxonomy, will result in the post being excluded.

In the case of the meta value, I'm JOINing to convert an attachment ID into a URL.

I've looked at OUTER LEFT JOINs and nested JOINS in order to get a result when a taxonomy join is not found, but have had no luck.

Comment: Did you try including [OR statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)?

Comment: I don't think a simple OR in the WHERE clause will cut it; the query will not pull records where the INNER JOINs fails.

Comment: Did you try using `LEFT JOIN`? Without inner? The left join will return null if the `ON` clause matches zero in the right table.

Answer (score 0):

I think the style of query I was attempting here was probably needlessly complex. An alternative, that yielded the same result, was to concatentate a series of queries, each of which could yield a result, or not, ie:

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_title
,(SELECT group_concat(wp_terms.name separator ', ') 
    FROM wp_terms
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy on wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
        INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr on wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE taxonomy= 'pm_type' and wp_posts.ID = wpr.object_id
 ) AS "type"

,(SELECT guid FROM wp_posts attachment
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta on wp_postmeta.meta_value = attachment.ID
    WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'pm_pdf_link' AND wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID) AS "pub_url"

    FROM wp_posts
    WHERE post_type = 'pressmention' 
    AND post_status = 'publish'
```

Although this probably does not perform as well as a single SELECT statement, it is easier to read and a will return a post record when only some of the taxonomies have values.